# SQL AVG() to 2 decimals

Tags: php, mysql, average

I'm trying to get this average to give me 2 decimals, so instead of 17.4534 I just get 17.45.  I tried various combinations using CAST in each of the 2 places I use AVG in, but can't seem to get anything to work.

This is my code that currently works to give the average (just with too many decimals).

```
<?php
$sql3 = "SELECT AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent) FROM app_tests"; 
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        echo "<h3>".$row3['AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent)'];
    }
?>
</h3><p>Average % Lift</p>
```

Comment: Here was the final code that did the trick:

 <?php
 $sql3 = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent),2) FROM app_tests"; 
 $result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error());
 while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
  {
   echo "<h3>".$row3[0];
  }
 ?>
 </h3><p>Average % Lift</p>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the `ROUND()` function would work?

```
$sql3 = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent),2) FROM app_tests";
```

**EDIT**

Your PHP looks strange. You should either alias the average function as a column and access it by that name, or access it by index. Something like

```
echo "<h3>".$row3[0];
```

Comment: Nailed it, THANK YOU!  In 5 mins it will let me mark this as the answer.

Comment: Happy to assist :)

Answer (score 0):

Round by two decimal places and then casting it will work.

```
SELECT cast(ROUND(AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent),2) as numeric(19,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **ROUND** function:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(app_tests.test_resultPercent), 2) FROM app_tests";
```